# Error in Mac when build a Maui project migrated from Xamarin

Tags: maui

I am migrating a Xamarin app to dotnet MAUI, and I have two projects:

- MyModel.cproj using .net Framwework 4.6.1 (reusing from Xamarin App, but it is a class Library)
- MyMauiApp.cproj using .net 8.0

In windows when I run the android app I do not have any problem, but in my Mac, when I tried to build the project it gives me the error, which tell to run "dotnet workloads restore", but when I do it this error appears:

*Project "............./MyMobileMaui.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):

---

Project "............./MyMobileMaui.csproj" is building "............./MyMobileMaui.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):

---

Project "............./MyMobileMaui.csproj" is building "............./MyModel.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):
"............./"............./MyModel.csproj" .csproj" : error MSB4057: The target "_GetRequiredWorkloads" does not existin the project.
Done building project "MyModel.csproj" .csproj" -- FAILED.
Failed to restore workload for project "............./MyMobileMaui.csproj" : Failed to run MSBuild Target _GetRequiredWorkloads.*

Should my MyModel.cproj a MAUI Class Library?

**EDIT** YES

But it gives an error

Error: Unable to create package spec for project. '............./MyMobileMaui.csproj' Please see the Package Console for more details. (MyMobileMaui)

Getting restore information for project '............./MyMobileMaui.csproj'
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5) : error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-tizen
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5) : error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-tizen
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.311/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5) : error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-tizen
To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore
Unable to create package spec for project. '............./MyMobileMaui.csproj'

I run the dotnet workloads restore and it gives me

Successfully installed workload(s) maui-tizen maui-ios maui-android maui.

But the same error happens again, and again...(I am using only IOS and Android targets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your comment, as an answer:

> Error in Mac when build a Maui project migrated from Xamarin, when I tried to build the project it gives me the error, which tell to run "dotnet workloads restore", but when I do it this error appears: .........

Using visual studio code instead of visual studio for Mac can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your MyModel.cproj to a net8 project or netstandard2.0 or 2.1

Comment: Rui just update the question, and I followed your recommendation using .net8 project

Comment: Can you clean your bin/obj .. if its a git repo do a `git clean -fdx` .
make sure there's none. Is MyModel.cproj a sdk style project? what's the TargetFramework there? maybe post your csproj

Comment: I am using visual studio code, and now it works, in visual studio for Mac does not